# How to configure Asterisk server in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, asterisk, freepbx

I have installed Asterisk server in ubuntu, I want to configure the asterisk server so my two clients 7001 and 7002 can communicate with eachother via, meessege, call and videocall.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! [Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that your question shows you did some **research**, found and **read the vendor documentation** and/or **tried a solution** before asking the internet for help. You're not expected to solve everything yourself, but then at least you can [write a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) that we can help you answer.